# Smooth Zooming in Canvas via button instead of mousewheel

Tags: javascript, canvas

**I am trying to implement something like a smooth zoom in a Canvas application.**

I am already able to zoom to a predefined zoom level using this:

```
 $("#zoomToView").click(function () {
    paper.view.zoom=5.0;
    });
```

Most of the examples for smooth zomming pertain to mouse-wheel implementations but I would like to use a button instead that zooms to a pre-defined level and back.

I have the impression that the implementantion has something to do with a FOR loop and some kind of adaptive delay that gets bigger as the loop count increases.

Any ideas?

*I am using [Paper.js](http://www.paperjs.org) as my canvas library but that should not be a factor in finding a solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using native canvas, but you can substitute paper.js if desired.

The concept is to continuously run an animation loop that only resizes the image if your button is down.

http://jsfiddle.net/SW5jL/3/

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;
    var iw,ih;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg";
    function start(){
        iw=img.width;
        ih=img.height;

        $("#test").mousedown(function(){ doAnimation=true; });
        $("#test").mouseup(function(){ doAnimation=false; });
        $("#test").mouseout(function(){ doAnimation=false; });

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        ctx.drawImage(img,cw/2-iw/2,ch/2-ih/2);

    }

    var scale=1.00;
    scaleDirection=0.01;
    var minScale=0.50;
    var maxScale=1.50;
    var doAnimation=false;

    function animate(){

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        if(doAnimation){

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img,
                0,0,iw,ih,
                (cw-iw*scale)/2,(ch-ih*scale)/2,iw*scale,ih*scale
            );

            scale+=scaleDirection;
            if(scale<minScale || scale>maxScale){
                scaleDirection*=-1;
                scale+=scaleDirection;
            }

        }

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test">Animate</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. The only real big difference is that I can zoom using paper.view.zoom in paper.js, so there is no need to take care of resizing the elements. Do you have the time to tell me what really needs to be removed and substituted in your example to do that? Your example runs nice.

Comment: Instead of `ctx.drawImage`, use the `scale` variable with your paper.view.zoom.  You could alternatively use .scale on layers or groups.